# How to get co-ordinates of a contour of a binary image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision, matlab-figure

I have a binary image and I want to extract the co-ordinates of the contour of the binary image.The built in contour() functions resulted in double values, but instead I want the array i.e. series of (x,y) of the contour.It is also ok if the co ordinates are in polar (x+iy) form. Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get you contour mask by eroding your mask with a simple small structure element (disk/square)

```
con = BW & ~imerode( BW, [0 1 0; 1 1 1; 0 1 0] ); 
figure; imshow( con ); title('contour mask');
[cy cx] = find(con); %// get coordinates of contour pixels
```

---

Coming to think about it, there are several (related) functions for tracing boundaries of binary masks in the image processing toolbox.

Have you tried [`bwtraceboundary`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwtraceboundary.html) or [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html)?

Comment: thanks .. it worked but it resulted in sorted order. cant we get co ordinates like from start point and end point i.e (x1,y1)(x2,y2)....(xn,yn) ? or in polar form like f(xn,yn) = xn+iyn ?

Comment: @codename_cipher tracing a border can be tricky. I'm not sure there is a trivial way. please see my edit.

Comment: @codename_cipher Tracing a boundary can easily be done with `bwtraceboundary`.  Shai has you on the right track.